# MS ACCESS database broken into month

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Back again with an issue that has been bugging me for sometime now. Here's my dilemma.
I have a table looks like this

```
| ID |   DATE         |  SALES |
  1     2012-01-20      100.45
  1     2012-01-22       55.45
  1     2012-02-15       66.77
  3     2012-01-19       33.33  
  3     2012-02-19       69.44
  4     2012-02-22       77.55
  etc
```

So what i need to do is make a new table with all the ID grouped in one, and then adding their sales in the month range (i.e `2012-01-01` to `2012-01-30`)

The new table would looke like this

```
ID    |   01-2012    |   02-2012   |  03-2012 | etc | etc
1     |   155.90     |     66.77   |
3     |  33.33       |     69.44   |
4     | 000.00       |    77.55    |
```

All the recoods need to display even if they sum up to none

any input or help is much appreciated! Thank you internet!

Comment: You need to transform data (pivot)! There's no need to export these data into another table.

Comment: Can you pivot a table in access??

Comment: Yes, you can. Please, see my answer.

Comment: Have a look at PIVOT. When you do your PIVOT you will need to manipulate the date so that it only looks at MM/YYYY otherwise you will end up with a column for every date in your data. Have a go, if you get stuck post your cose and we will have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot data by using [Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx) command.

```
TRANSFORM SUM(SALES)
SELECT ID, FORMAT([DATE], 'yyyy-MM')
FROM YourTableName
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN #Date1# AND #Date2#
GROUP BY ID, FORMAT([DATE], 'yyyy-MM')
```

Replace Date1 and Date2 with proper dates (in ISO format: MM/dd/yyyy).

By The Way: never use reserved words as a column name!

See: [SQL Reserved Words](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you transform and also Sum by groupped date?

Comment: As i mentioned: Yes, you can!

Comment: the column nmaes were abritutary for example purposes :) Thank you will test this out

Comment: Okay it worked  but needed to add the pivot Sales at the end

new problem however, i'm now getting an error that says it's making to many columns can i break this out into years there is 5 years of data in this table?

Comment: Define date range for example for one month o group data by month, year.

Comment: would i through the where after the from table like so
((date Between #1/1/2010# And #1/31/2010#))? if it was for one month period? also i should mention my date data has time

Comment: ??? i can't get you, sorry...

Comment: sorry hit enter to soon, see above note

Comment: Yes, you can use above WHERE statement. Please, see updated answer ;)

Comment: Okay that worked a bit better, howver it's putting every single column in the header that has a differnt time stamp, how can i prevent the pivot from looking at individual time stamp and just group the actual day together

Comment: all the table headings are 2012-01-01 9:25:35am 2012-01-01 10:10:20am we need to group those into the same day

Comment: Or better group them into the same month

Comment: Feel free to add **MONTH([DATE])** or **FORMAT([DATE],"YYYY/MM/DD")** function ;)

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your quick response. really appreciate. I'm fairly new to access and have not used the format function where would this be placed in the SQl

Comment: Answer has been updated again ;)

Comment: Thanks again worked perfect! Although i have one more task at hand but i'll most likely post a follow up question with you :)

Comment: Thank you for recognition. Please, post another question. There's tons of experts ;) Someone will help you. Maybe it would be me ;)